# Compile Error: Syntax Error MS Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm fairly new to Access and am attempting to make a searchable form, where the the form returns all entrees that meet all of the criteria in several text boxes.  I found a code online that should do exactly what I need

http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62code.html

But I am running into errors when I try to run in for myself.  I am currently just trying to link up one textbox before adding on several others.  Here is my code thus far:

```
Private Sub SearchAll_Click()

If Not IsNull(Me.txtCityCounty) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([City/County] Like "" * " & Me.txtCityCounty & " * """)"

    End If

End Sub
```

When I try to run it, I get "Compile Error:  Syntax Error" and the line "Private Sub SearchAll_Click()" is highlighted in yellow.

If it helps:  "SearchAll" is my button, "txtCityCounty" is the textbox, "City/County" is the field name.  I'm currently using Access 2013.

Any and all help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You need to use `Me.txtCityCounty.Text`, if my memory serves me correctly  (in both places you reference it - a TextBox on a form can't possibly be null). You can't concatenate a string and a textbox; you need to use the textbox contents instead.

Comment: Access forms are different - `Textbox.Text` is only available if it has the focus (which it hasn't, since we are in a Button_Click event). `Me.txtCityCounty` is shorthand for `Me.txtCityCounty.Value` and perfectly ok for string concatenation. An empty textbox actually is Null, not `""`. @KenWhite

Comment: @Andre: I guess my memory did not serve me correctly. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in your code which says

```
strWhere = strWhere & "([City/County] Like "" * " & Me.txtCityCounty & " * """)"
```

should be shown in red, indicating that it is the line where the syntax error was detected.

If you look at that line you will notice that your double-quotation marks are not matched.  I suspect you intended it to be:

```
strWhere = strWhere & "([City/County] Like "" * " & Me.txtCityCounty & " * "")"
```

or, maybe, just

```
strWhere = strWhere & "([City/County] Like ""*" & Me.txtCityCounty.Text & "*"")"
```

depending on how you want the wildcard to work.  (I believe your current test will be for a space, followed by any number of characters, followed by a space, followed by your City/County textbox value, followed by a space, followed by any number of characters, followed by a space.)

Comment: Don't use `.Text`, see comment on the question.

Comment: @Andre - I tried with `Me.txtCityCounty` and it was saying it was `Null` - I needed to use `.Text` to get to the contents.  But let me go and play a bit more and see what I can see.

Comment: @Andre - Don't know what I did earlier, but this time it is behaving as you say.  Answer edited accordingly.  Thanks for the info.  :)

Comment: @YowE3K Awesome!  That did indeed take away the red text, and I no longer get an error message, thank you.  I'm having difficulty with it displaying the information now.  It "filters," but it just wipes away the information below, no values display.  I'm using a continuous form, which was suggested on that web page.  Is there another line of code I need to enter to display the information? Sorry if this is an obvious question.

Comment: @SarahCathrynAshworth - Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with Access to know what your next issue is.  The code you posted should just append a piece of text to an existing string (which I assume must be a variable declared at a module level?).  It doesn't actually do any data manipulation, or modify the form itself - but maybe you have other code which uses `strWhere` as part of a query after this code runs.  I think you will have to post a new question for the new issue.

Comment: @YowE3K - Thank you :)